# LINQ select List where sub-list all items contains another list

Tags: c#, linq

I have a model with list items.

```
public class Semester{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public List<SemesterParent> Parents { get; set; }
}

public class SemesterParent{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int SemesterId { get; set; }
    public int ParentId { get; set; }
}
```

I have a `list<int>` of `parentids`. I want to get `semester` list that `Parents` in `parentids` list.

For example

```
Semester{1,{}}
Semester{2,{}}
Semester{3,{1,2}}
Semester{4,{1}}
Semester{5,{2,4}}
```

When I have ParentIdes `{1,2}` the result is:

```
Semester{3,{1,2}}
Semester{4,{1}}
```

I use this code.

```
var parentIds =
            await _semesterTermStudentService.Select(m => m.IsAccept && m.StudentId == student.Id);
var semester=await _semesterService.FindAsync(m=>
             m.Parents.Any(y => parentIds.Contains(y.ParentId)));
```

Comment: why not `Semester{5,{2,4}}` in the result?

Comment: I agree with @SowmyadharGourishetty, there isn't an explanation on why inputs {1, 2} retrieves parentids only containing 1 but not parentids that only contain 2.

Comment: @Hayden, I later saw the title `LINQ select List where sub-list all items contains another list` it says all items that match the parentId's

Comment: @SowmyadharGourishetty Thanks for pointing that out, just not clear in the question itself.

Answer (score 2):

You can do as below. [Here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/sUK3M1) is the working code

```
List<Semester> s = new List<Semester>();
var parentIds = new List<int> { 1, 2 };
var result = s.Where(x => x.Parents != null && x.Parents.Any() && x.Parents.All(y => parentIds.Contains(y.Id))).ToList();
```

Comment: If you want to include the list if it atleast has any one of the parentId's, you can use `Any` instead of `All` in the above Linq

Comment: Thanks, when i use this , find all items that contains `id` but i want to select items that every item list in list.

Comment: @ar.gorgin Yes, this works in the same way. can you please check the working code attached

Comment: You are almost there, instead of `m.Parents.Any` try `m.Parents.All`. Which I have already mentioned in my answer. please check my answer again

Comment: i use `All` , this return items like `Any` and item with this id.

Comment: Did you see the attached working code? I have pasted a url